# use unique_ptr to wrap and unwrap void*

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

My goal is to create unique_ptr<void*> where void* can point to any object type. This gives me a way to use unique_ptr to point to state object that shares the same signature. But below code doesn't seem to match my expectation where p.get() should be equal to v and s1 address. I suspect it has to do the line that try to wrap a unqiue_ptr on top of s1 to own it. But address has changed.

```
struct State1 
{
public:
  std::string name;
  std::string address;
};

int main() {

  auto s1 = new State1;
  s1->name = "name";
  std::cout<<"s1 address: "<<s1<<"\n";
  auto v = (void*)s1;
  std::cout<<"v address: "<<v<<"\n";
  auto p = std::make_unique<void*>(s1);
  std::cout<<"p.get address: "<<p.get()<<"\n";
  auto r =  static_cast<State1*>((void*)p.get());
  std::cout<<"r address: "<<r<<"\n";
}

s1 address: 0x55dcf389aeb0
v address: 0x55dcf389aeb0
p.get address: 0x55dcf389b310
r address: 0x55dcf389b310
```

Comment: `delete p;` of a `p` that's `void*` won't turn out well.  You'll have to supply your own `delete`r to unique_ptr that can cast the pointer to the proper type to delete it.

Comment: _"My goal is to create unique_ptr<void*> where void* can point to any object type."_ I don't understand what's the purpose of this. A `std::unique_ptr<T>` already can point to any `T`?!?

Comment: "*My goal is to create `unique_ptr<void*>` where `void*` can point to any object type*" - that is not how `std::unique_ptr` should be used.  Why do you want this exactly? Perhaps `std::any` would make more sense instead?

Answer (score 1):

`std::unique_ptr<void*>` is a unique **pointer to a pointer** to void. A pointer to an object is separate from the pointed object. In other words, the pointer and the pointed object have distinct addresses. The value of the pointer to void is the address of the pointed object while the value of a pointer to pointer to void is the address of the pointer to void that points to the object.

`p.get()` gives you the address of (i.e. a pointer to) the `void*` object that the unique pointer owns. In order to get the pointer to void from (unique) pointer to pointer to void, you must indirect through the (unique) pointer to pointer to void. This gives the address that is equal to `s1` and `v`:

```
std::cout << *p;
```

---

P.S. You never delete the dynamically allocated `State1`, and as such you have a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

`std::unique_ptr<void*>` is a smart pointer to a pointer.

You want `unique_ptr<void>` as a first step.

The next thing you need is to reach that unique ptr how to delete the resource; by default, unique ptr just calls delete, and that isn't going to work on a void pointer.  It has no way to know the type stored in a void pointer, so no way to call the destructor.

```
template<class T>
std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)>
wrap_ptr(T* ptr){
  return {ptr, [](void*ptr){ delete static_cast<T*>(ptr); }};
}
```

here we remember how to delete the object by storing a function pointer to code that knows the real type.

```
auto p = wrap_ptr(s1);
```

and I suspect the code does what you want.

As an aside, `((void*)p.get())` that C cast hid an error message saying what you did wrong. Avoid using C style casts.

That fact you are reinterpreting a `void**` to a `void*` should have been a red flag.